# JPA Criteria API join

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

Help me plz with one moment. I read about 10 articles already, but don't understand join moment. I have 2 tables:

```
public class News implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue (generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator (name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private int id;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private Date created;
@Column
private String data;
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name = "category_id")
private NewsCategoryDict category;
// getters, setters
}
```

and

```
public class NewsCategoryDict implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue (generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator (name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private int id;
@Column
private String name;
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want a query works like

```
SELECT * FROM news, categorynews WHERE news.category_id = categorynews.id;
```

And then get the result in jsp with

```
    <div id="list_news">
        <c:forEach items="${news}" var="news">
            <h5>${news.id} : ${news.name} - ${news.created} ; ${news.data} (${news.category.name})</h5>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

And I just can't understand this JOIN with Criteria API. Can you help me ?
Try to use this snippet, but get a error

```
public List<News> getAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<News> cq = cb.createQuery(News.class);
    Root<News> rootFromNews = cq.from(News.class);
    Join<NewsCategoryDict, News> join = rootFromNews.join("category");
    cq.select(join);

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

> PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'created' not found on type ru.r1k0.spring.model.NewsCategoryDict

Comment: You write: *I want a query works like: *  `SELECT * FROM news, categorynews`. This query returns all the data in both tables. But you write in the comment to the answer below: *but I want List<News>*. So what do you want? If you want a list of `News` why do you need a **JOIN*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return an instance of `News` associated to an instance of `NewsCategoryDict`, your criteria query should look as follows:

```
public List<News> getAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<News> cq = cb.createQuery(News.class);
    Root<News> rootFromNews = cq.from(News.class);
    Join<News, NewsCategoryDict> join = rootFromNews.join("category"); // #1
    cq.select(rootFromNews);  // #2

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

The modified lines are marked with `#1` and `#2` comments.

The query should return all `News` which have a matching `NewsCategoryDict`; but `News` records which are not associated to a`NewsCategoryDict` record will not be returned.

Comment: Each news always has category_id from NewsCategoryDict. So even if its true - I try your decision, but got a NullPointerException with, I think, this snippet: ${news.category.name}. How can I get access to this field in jsp?

Comment: You are getting NPE because you're  loading `category` **lazily**. So change the `@ManyToOne` annotation to `@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` or remove the `fetch` option as eager is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with the join! What is actually happening is that in the  JSP fragment you are trying to access **${news.created}**  which does not exist in the **NewsCategoryDict**. I believe the error is in the JSP fragment, not in the Criteria query.

The way I understand it is that you want to list the News object, but in the query you are selecting the NewsCategoryDict and this is why at the end you end up with missing attribute because the NewsCategoryDict does not contain **${news.created}**

Comment: Yes. I undestand this, But if I try to use Join<News, NewsCategoryDict> then em.createQuery(cq).getResultList() returns List<NewsCategoryDict> but I want List<News>

Comment: Two questions, do you realy need to join ?  you need only the News then you most probably dont. I pressume though that in another fragment of the JSP page you need it. In that case you need to select the root, not the join like this:   cq.select(rootFromNews );  this will select you the News.

Comment: Yes I realy need a join 'cos News has a category_id and NewsCategoryDict has name associated with this ID. I want News object with filled category attribute to get a name of category with as one entity,